# How to debug "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException" in a Java program?

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
//import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Unos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
  boolean run = true;
//String ispisID;
  int proveraID;
  int broj = 0;
  int brojT = 0;
  String id;
  String provera2;
  String provera3;
  String ime;
  String prezime;
  String godina;
  String mesec;
  String dan;

  while(run) {

  brojT  = broj;
  ArrayList<String> imena = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> prezimena = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> godine = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> meseci = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> dani = new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<String> ids = new ArrayList<String>();
//char pocetak='s';
  System.out.println("Za pocetak pritisnuti s, za pretagu pritisnuti p");
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  String provera = input.nextLine();
  if(provera.equals("s")) {
      System.out.println("Unesite ime");
      ime = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Unesite prezime");
      prezime = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Unesite godinu rodjenja");
      godina = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Unesite mesec");
      mesec = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Unesite dan");
      dan = input.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Da li je profil dobro unet?");
     // brojT++;
      System.out.println("ID: " + brojT);
      System.out.println(ime + " " + prezime );
      System.out.println(dan + "/" + mesec + "/" + godina);
      System.out.println("T= tacno, N= netacno");
      provera2 = input.nextLine();
      if(provera2.equals("t")) {
          broj = brojT;
          imena.add(ime);
          prezimena.add(prezime);
          godine.add(godina);
          meseci.add(mesec);
          dani.add(dan);
          System.out.println("Memorisano u bazu, za prikaz pritisnuti p, na ponovno unosenje s");
          provera3 = input.nextLine();
          switch(provera3) {
          case "p":
              System.out.println(ime + " " + prezime );
              System.out.println(dan + "/" + mesec + "/" + godina);
          break;
          case "s":

          break;
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Nije memorisano");
          brojT--;
      }
  } else if(provera.equals("p")) {
      System.out.println("Unesite id");
      proveraID = input.nextInt();
      String ispisID = (String) ids.get(proveraID);
      System.out.println(ispisID);



  }
}
}
}
```

Here is error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0,          Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at Unos.main(Unos.java:78)
```

Thank you for help, I'm new to Java.

Also I have Eclipse Oxygen so maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Sorry for little spam, i really did not know what to write.. :)

Comment: you didn't add anything in `ids` list hence the issue `ids.get(proveraID)` plus you don't need to cast

Comment: you're having a problem in here. String ispisID = (String) ids.get(proveraID); it is out of bounds

Comment: Read about breakpoints, and debugging. It's really easy.  Then you can step through your code, and see what value variables have, and why things break.

Comment: your run variable always set to true, and causing  infinite loop and probably that why you getting error outOfBondException

Comment: do i have to write it like this: ids.get(3) or i can write it like this: int l = 3; ids.get(l)?

Answer (score 0):

In the biggest else you read the variable ids, but it may not have nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding anything to the Arraylist *ids* (List ids is empty).
That is why while trying to get elements you are getting this exception.
So before accessing a particular element make sure its available.
So enclose below line

```
String ispisID = (String) ids.get(proveraID);
```

as follows:

```
if(!ids.isEmpty() && proveraID<ids.size()){
        String ispisID = (String) ids.get(proveraID);
    }
```

Comment: i want my code to search through lists like this: you type id 0 and program prints out from lists with index 0. will that work for my code?

Comment: yes, that can be done. But before accessing you have to add contents/elements to the list. That's it.

Comment: i added elements:imena.add(ime);
        prezimena.add(prezime);
        godine.add(godina);
        meseci.add(mesec);
        dani.add(dan); but it is not working

Comment: did you add elements to ids list?
NO. Still you haven't added elements to ids list